# 'Text' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to show my machine learning project through web-based and using voila

```
text = widgets.Text(placeholder='Input text here')

button_send = widgets.Button(
                description='Identify gender',
                tooltip='Send',
                style={'description_width': 'initial'}
            )

output = widgets.Output()

def on_button_clicked(event):
    with output:
        clear_output()
        features = find_features(top_words, text)
        print("Naive Bayes = " + NB_classifier.classify(features))
        
button_send.on_click(on_button_clicked)

vbox_result = widgets.VBox([button_send, output])

text_0 = widgets.HTML(value="<h1>Hello!</h1>")
text_1 = widgets.HTML(value="<h2>Type anything</h2>")

vbox_text = widgets.VBox([text_0, text_1, text, vbox_result])

page = widgets.HBox([vbox_headline, vbox_text])
display(page)
```

and i got this following callback after input the text:
[my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3PpQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your `text` object is an object that is of the  type `ipywidgets.widgets.widget_string.Text`.

The `.lower()` method, that appears to be used as part of the processing in `find_features()` is for strings.

For passing to `find_features` therefore you want the string object contained in your `text` object.

Your line should be:

```py
features = find_features(top_words, text.value)
```